# when using this statement =DAYS360 I need statement to return text when a cell in blank

Tags: excel

I am using the statement =DAYS360(A2,B2) I need the statement to return an text 'Open' when cell B2 is empty

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using an IF condition in your formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"Open",DAYS360(A2,B2))
```